# Javascript array 100000 x 100000 - kill my browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm trying to construct such array ( Matrix ):

```
var arr = [];
var matrix_size = 100000;
var start_time = Math.round(new Date().getTime()) / 1000.0;

for( var i = 0; i < matrix_size ; i++ ) {
   var row = [];
   for( var j = 0; j < matrix_size; j++ ) {
       row.push( 0 );
   }
   arr.push( row );
   if ( counter % 10 == 0 ) {
      var stop_time = Math.round(new Date().getTime()) / 1000.0;
      var speed_time =  stop_time - start_time;
      var speed = i / speed_time; // m / s
      var remain = matrix_size - i;
      var remain_time = remain / speed;
      console.log("Ready: " + i + " rows; remain: " + remain + "; speed: " + speed + "; remain_time: " + remain_time + "s.");
  }
}

var stop_time = Math.round(new Date().getTime()) / 1000.0;
var speed_time =  stop_time - start_time;
console.log( "Time: " + speed_time + " s. ");
```

- matrix_size 1000 - 0.1700000762939453 seconds
- matrix_size 10000 - 8.978000164031982 seconds
- matrix_size 100000 - stuck

`Ready: 1020 rows; remain: 98980; speed: 40.255742648097055; remain_time: 2458.7796296605875s.`

Is it really such large? What is the right math for power of browser in such case?

Actually, me needs 500,000 x 500,000 array. Not with just zeros, but real float values. Am I need to use server side in this situation?

Comment: Javascript is an interpreted language, which means it's slow.

Comment: 500K * 500K = 250 billion. Even assuming that you can do 1 thing per hertz on your processor, that should be an incredibly long time.

Comment: Not just time but memory, 250 billion x 64bits

Comment: @user299448 What are you doing that you need such a large matrix? Will a database not suffice?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do or why, but I'd recommend you look into some kind of [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units). WebGL would be the way to go if you *need* to do it in a browser (although I don't have a lot of experience with it, so I'm not sure if it would do what you need).

Comment: @Mr. Concolato, I'm trying to construct sortable table over this data. Looks like you are right, more than 10k x 10k - is a sql job.

Comment: Is it by any chance a sparse matrix? If so then you could somehow make an array containing only the nonzero values. How many nonzero values are in it?

Comment: @user299448 In that case i have posted a recommended approach below. What kind of data are you working with? If it is Geo-Spacial for example you could use Postgres and PostGIS if you're considering a database.

Answer (score 2):

500Kx500K is way too much for Javascript to handle (and big enough for a reasonable computer to choke on it), but if you're still willing to work with huge datasets on the client side, I suggest you look into this: http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

> Crossfilter is a JavaScript library for exploring large multivariate
>   datasets in the browser. Crossfilter supports extremely fast (<30ms)
>   interaction with coordinated views, even with datasets containing a
>   million or more records.

This won't solve your problem, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction. I would suggest to break up your datasets into multiple parts and work on them separately. It is usually wiser to work on small chunks of data rather than huge datasets.

Comment: I doubt even crossfilter could handle it.  We're not talking about merely *millions*.  This is a quarter of a *trillion*.  It wouldn't even fit in the memory of most server-class machines.

Answer (score 2):

500,000 x 500,000 is 250 billion values. Each number in javascript is 8 bytes (according to a quick Google search at least).

In order to just store only the numbers in memory, you'll need over 1862.65 GB of memory (not counting any of the overhead involved in having the array, the browser, the javascript engine, etc).

Even server-side solutions would have issues with that much data. You should spend time re-evaluating your problem, and finding ways to reduce your data set earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in comments a 500K x 500K matrice of doubles is going to be roughly 1.8 To of memory.

There is actually no chance you'll be able to handle that. But the upside is that there is probably no chance that you have that much data to process. And in the browser? I wonder *how* you would have gotten the data there in the first place!

You haven't described the *actual* problem that you're trying to solve, so it's hard to help you. A few random tips:

- Your matrice may have a 500K dimension but it's probably mostly empty. You should look into using a *sparse* data structure and algorithms. A *sparse* datastructure doesn't store *all* entries in memory. Only those that are *not empty*.
- If you work on large amount of data you should try to process it in a *streaming* fashion. That is: on slices of data, never loading the whole dataset in memory. That won't make it *faster*, but it can make it *doable*.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a database to formulate your data. You will be able to handle computational requirements by leveraging the power of a database since your matrix is so large. You can then query the DB and use server side code (PHP, Python, Java etc) to build a JSON object and traverse your data that way. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score -1):

All JavaScript numbers are double-precision floating point numbers, meaning 8 bytes each. 500K x 500K x 8B turns out to be approximately 2000 GB of memory. So the "power of browser" needed in this case will be a web browser running on a machine with over 2000GB of memory, and a browser whose JavaScript memory manager will support that amount (Chrome's V8 engine starts struggling, in my experience, around 2GB).